# WPF : How to move a maximized custom window?

Tags: wpf, move, maximize-window

I'm working on a custom window to add more styling to my application.

I followed some tutorials to enable basic window behaviors :

- Closing
- Maximizing
- Minimizing
- Moving
- Resizing

These are all okay.

I would like what is I believe a Windows 7 functionnality :
When a window is maximized, I can still drag it to another screen, where it will kept its maximized state.

Do you have any Idea how I could do this?

PS : The tutorials I used :

- Create a custom Window : http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm
- Resizing : http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=256
- Other resizing :http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ResizingCustomWPFWindow.aspx

Thanks a lot,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Thumb` in your title bar, you can subscribe to the `DragDelta` event and wait until `WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && dragEventArgs.Y > 100` to restore the window.

Comment: Sorry, a year late, but that's a good idea! I also was trying to create a new Window (Inheriting of the window class, as a UserControl), but I could only create a new template for the window, as Decyclone said.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to implement something that Windows already does for you?

That feature is `Windows 7` specific and even if you create a custom template for your window, windows will take care of it. Now, I guess all you would have to do is call `DragMove()` from a thumb by which you enable moving of window.

Comment: Hello Decyclone, that's what I've done, but it doesn't gives you the Windows 7 maximizing behavior, nor the one that gives a window half the screen width (when dragging it to the left or right side of the screen).